# Вопросы вместо русских букв

Tags: html, mysql, кодировка

Здравствуйте.

Начал переводить сайт на русский, но возникла проблема - вопросы вместо русских букв стало показывать. Проблема связана, думаю, с mysql, так как внутри сайта вопросы появляются вместо букв, только когда с базы данные. В базе поставил utf-8_bin, тоже не помогло. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: а на самом сайте какая кодировка?

Comment: здесь много факторов: кодировка файла, кодировка тега meta, кодировка базы, наличие запроса SET NAMES utf-8 или cp1251, заголовки header() и тд. нужно все проверять

Comment: htaccess написано utf-8 , в html text/html; charset=utf-8 @Perkovec @mountpoint

Comment: в базе русские буквы нормально отображаются?

Comment: да @mountpoint

Comment: наличие запроса SET NAMES utf-8 ??

Comment: сделал не помогло @mountpoint 
    function connect(){
    $conn = new mysqli($this->host,  $this->name,  $this->pass,$this->dbname) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
   mysqli_query("SET NAMES utf-8");
  return $conn;
    }

Comment: кодировка самого файла? Должно быть, к примеру, UTF-8 БЕЗ BOM

Comment: @fikos, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 10):

1) для Apache в **.htaccess**:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

2) для nginx в конфиге:

```
charset utf8;
```

3) в **html-документе**:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
```

html 5 версия:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

4) необходимо все сущности (таблицы) установить в кодировку `utf8_general_ci`

5) если используете PDO:

```
new \PDO(
    'mysql:
    host=localhost;
    dbname=db;
    charset=utf8;',
    'user',
    'pass'
)
```

6) если всё ещё пользуетесь процедурным доступом к БД, то:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES "utf8"');
```

7) в Вашем редакторе/IDE сохраняйте файл в кодировке `utf8`

Comment: $conn->set_charset("utf8"); // у вас было mysqli_query('SET NAMES "utf8"') в другом месте 
return $conn; 
} 
Исправил в ru/inc/db.php, заработало

Comment: Если вы используете `SET NAMES "utf8"` и вообще кодировку `utf8` то у вас в БД [не будут сохраняться смайлы и прочий современный уникод](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hLeNFpY6fYF6Ba2FoR5RaL/0). Не просто не будут сохраняться, а запросы будут заканчиваться ошибкой. Одумайтесь, уже 21 век на дворе!

Answer (score 1):

Если не разберетесь с кодировкой из базы, то можете на невысоконагруженном проекте, например, конвертировать iconv налету все переменные.

**Обновление**

```
$out=iconv( mb_detect_encoding($in), 'UTF-8', $in)
```

где-то как-то так:

`$in` - строка в любой кодировке
`$out` - строка в `utf-8`

Comment: Сайт не высоко нагруженный @Михаил Колев

Comment: поздравляем, теперь ваш проект высоконагруженный )

Answer (score 1):

У меня скрипты и html странички к ним крутились на виндовс серваке, а потом все на линукс перенесли и там вместо русского были ромбики с вопросами.
Нашел сначала в нете вариант через notepad++ сам html фалик сохранять в спец кодировке.
Но это не дело так с каждым делать.
Решение такое, заходите в httpd.conf файл апача.
(у меня по умолчанию /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf)
И там в начале есть параметр AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Я заменил UTF-8 на windows-1251 
и далее рестартанул сервак
systemctl restart httpd
и русский заработал на страничках в браузере.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема, скорее всего, в кодировке HTML редактора, которым вы пользуетесь. Редактор может выставлять кодировку записанного файла в соответствии с языковой версией Windows. Например, на английской версии  редактор может записывать в ANSI, чего не понимается браузерами.

**Решение:** Кодировка HTML страницы должна совпадать с кодировкой указанной в HTML тэгом. Для универсальной UTF-8 которая сегодня используется по умолчанию в большинстве блогах и т.п. HTML страница начинается с тэгов типа

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Тогда текстовый редактор должен записывывать в UTF8:

[image: вопросы вместо русских букв]

В HTML редакторе настройка может быть во время Save а может где-то в Settings а может вообще не быть.

Answer (score 0):

В редакторе - сохранить как... и в поле кодировка поставь UTF-8.