# Кодировка вывода при использовании метода $_GET

Tags: php, sql, кодировка

При выводе `$_GET` через `var_dump()` скрипт выводит "кракозябры". Как сделать так, чтобы слова отображались правильно?

Comment: Результат var_dump-а string(2) "Р°"

Comment: Для Apache в .htaccess: `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` или для nginx: `charset utf8;`. [Вот ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/386787/10551) на мой полный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых выставите кодировку файла в `UTF-8`
Во-вторых укажите кодировку для браузера, либо через [заголовки](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) либо через [мета тег](http://htmlbook.ru/html/meta/charset).

PHP

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
?>
```

HTML

```
...
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Либо поменять кодировку файла, либо при передаче параметров обрабатывать их функцией `urlencode` например

```
echo '<a href="/?name=' . urlencode('Вася Пупкин') . '">';
```

И в итоге на выходе мы получаем следующую ссылку

```
href="/?name=%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD"
```

Переменные в суперглобальных массивах `$_GET` и `$_REQUEST` уже декодированы, поэтому обрабатывать эту переменную нужно также как и обычную

Comment: Я сделал следующую конструкция скрипта 
$sd= urlencode($_GET['sd']); и sql запрос SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '$sd' но результаты не выводятся в var_dump значение передано закодированние