# Знаки вопроса вместо русского текста

Tags: html

Вместо русского текста отображаются знаки вопроса.
Прописано ''
В коде присутствует php. При запуске на локальной машине все нормально, а когда запускаешь с сервера, то русские символы становятся знаками вопроса. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего у Вас проблема с настройками кодировки сервера.
Вот в [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/386724/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2) теме человек дал очень развернутый ответ.

Answer (score -1):

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Допишите и все будет отображаться.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?