# Почему русские буквы отображаются вопросами?

Tags: mysql

Использую mysql на ubuntu. При сохранении в БД русские символы заменяются вопросами, английские сохраняются корректно. На Windows таких проблем не было.

Следующие настройки не помогли:

`spring.datasource.tomcat.connection-properties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;`
`spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sweater?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8`

Также выставлял кодировку в `workbench Character set: utf8mb4` и `Collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci` - не помогло.

Шапка html-документа:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Main</title>
</head>
```

Отличие от [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/386724/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2) в том, что у меня уже в БД русские символы отображаются вопросами.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вопросы вместо русских букв](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/386724/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2)

Comment: там он пишет, что в БД у него нормально русские символы отображаются. У меня в БД они вопросами сохраняются.

Comment: Непонятно, какая софтина добавляет данные в базу. А именно от неё всё и зависит

Comment: в идее везде UTF-8 выставил. Использую шаблонизатор thymeleaf. Spring-Boot, Spring-MVC, Spring-data-jpa

Comment: проверьте кодировку самого файла в котором данные сохраняются в БД...одна из причин на которую редко обращают внимание

Answer (score 0):

При создании БД указал такие настройки и в proporties прописал следующее:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sweater?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]